# Understanding how to rigorously prove the supremum of a set is a given number

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Im thinking of the following set of real numbers

$$ S = \left\{ \dfrac{m}{n} : m,n \in \mathbb{N} \; \text{and} \; \; m < 2n \right\}  $$

Certainly, since $n > 0$, one has that $\dfrac{m}{n} < 2 $ $\; \; \;$ ${\bf \forall} m,n$.

I want to claim that $\sup S = 2 $. If $u$ is an upper bound of $S$ that is if $ \dfrac{m}{n} \leq u $ for all $m,n$, ${\bf then}$ if we somehow can manage to prove that $2 \leq u$, then we would have proved our statement.

I ${\bf Dont}$ see a way to prove this directly (Is it possible??) so I would argue by contradiction. What if there is a $u_0$ such that $u_0 < 2 $, then $2 - u_0 > 0$ and by the archimedean principle there is a natural number $N$ such that $\dfrac{1}{N} < 2 -u_0 $

Next, $N(2-u_0) > 0$ so again can find natural $M$ so that $M > N(2-u_0)$ and thus

$$ \dfrac{M}{N} > 2-u_0 > \dfrac{1}{N} $$

But, I dont see how to derive a contradiction from here. Am I on the right track?

As for the infimum, I can see that $\inf S \geq 0$, But I get stuck here again trying to show that this lower bound is actually the greatest. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not useful to have $\frac MN >2-u_0$. Instead of this choose $N$ such that $\frac 1 N <2-u_0$ and take $M=2N-1$. Then $\frac M N >u_0$. Thus, for every $u_0 <2$ there is an  element $\frac M N$ of our set which is greater than $u_0$. This proves that the supremum is $2$.

For the infimum use the fact that for any $\epsilon >0$ we can choose $n$ such that $\frac  1 n <\epsilon$  and $\frac  1 n$ is an element of the given set. Hence the infimum is $0$.

Comment: I dont understand how to take $M$?

Comment: @James You want an integer less than $2N$. A natural choice is $M=2N-1$.

Comment: I got it! As for the infimum: We claim that $\inf S = 0$ so if $x \geq l$ for all $l$ we prove that $0 \geq l$. If not, then $l > 0$ and choose $2N$ s.t $l > \frac{1}{N}$. and this already gives a contradction because $1/N \in S$. Is this correct profesor Kavi?

Comment: @James You are right.I was typing essentially the same answer when you were typing your comment!

Comment: Thanks prof. Kavi!

Answer (score 2):

0) $2$ is an upper bound of $S$, since $m/n < 2n/n =2$

2) Consider the sequence $a_n=\frac{2n-1}{n}=2-1/n \in S;$

Assume $b <2$ is a smaller upper bound of $S$.

$|a_n-2|=|-1/n|=1/n$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ given.

Archimedean principle:

There is a $n_0$ s.t. $n_0 >1/\epsilon$.

For $n\ge n_0$ we have

$|a_n-2| =1/n < 1/n_0 <\epsilon;$

$2 -\epsilon <a_n < 2+\epsilon;$

Choose $\epsilon =2-b(>0)$:

Then $b <a_n$, a contradiction .

Answer (score 1):

If $s\in S$, then $s$ can be written as $\frac mn$ with $m,n\in\Bbb N$ and $m<2n$. Then $s=\frac mn<2$ and therefore $2$ is an upper bound of $S$.

If $u<2$, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n}{n+1}=2$, $\frac{2n}{n+1}>2$ if $n$ is large enough, and therefore $u$ is not an upper bound of $S$.

So, $2$ is the least upper bound of $S$ and therefore $2=\sup S$.

You can prove that $\inf S=0$ in a similar way.

Comment: Jose, thanks for your input! What if using $lim$ is not allowed. Here part of the exercise is to show it from first principles: Just concept of supremum/infimum and the archimidean property. Is my approach correct?

Comment: Then you use the fact that $2-\frac{2n}{n+1}=\frac2{n+1}$, which is a small as you wish, by the Archimedian property.